# How to broadcast update operation to numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Say I have an array 
`A = [[0,1], [2,3]]`
which is shape (2,2). 
Then say I want to update the 0th row of A to [4,4], and the 1st row of A to [8,8], where the output is a new array of shape (2,2,2)

```
C = [[[4,4],[2,3]], 
      [0,1],[8,8]]]
```

I want to do this without using a for-loop, ie, I want to do this using numpy's vectorizing features.
Thanks

Comment: Hi, so what is C a list of list, an array? Have a look at numpy indexing : https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html

Comment: You can't do this with vectorizing per-se. The operation you are asking for is a memory reallocation. It's no more vectorized than np.append or np.stack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're concatenating and reshaping three arrays:

```
np.concatenate(([[4, 4]], A, [[8, 8]]), axis=0).reshape(2, 2, 2).transpose(1, 0, 2)
```